# synonym request - gam and general additive model

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

The tag wiki for [gam](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gam) says "general additive model", and has 44 questions. There is also [general-additive-model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-additive-model), which has 6 questions.

Please can someone with the required privileges establish the synonym?

Comment: Done--thanks.  I am closing this in light of a common meta thread we use to suggest tag synonyms; it helps keep such suggestions together.

Comment: @whuber Surely this should have been "general**ized**-additive-model"! How do we edit tags to correct them?

Comment: Gavin You're right: the "ized" version is used about ten times as often as the un-"ized" version on the Web.  Mods can edit tags at your suggestion.  This suggestion seems sufficiently well supported as to require no Meta discussion, so I have made the change.